# Is it possible to get Kerberos logging using gssapi inside secure context?

Tags: python, kerberos, gssapi

I am using [`gssapi`](https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi) to create a Flask server that is protected by Kerberos authentication. I am wanting to debug some Kerberos errors I am seeing and hence I would like to turn on debug logging by means of the [`KRB5_TRACE` environmental variable](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/troubleshoot.html):

```
KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout
```

However, no logs are created, but they are created when I set that environmental variable and call `kinit`, meaning that my version of Kerberos supports this variable but it's just `python-gssapi` that isn't respecting that variable.

In the documentation linked to above, it states:

> Some programs do not honor KRB5_TRACE, ... because they use secure
> library contexts

When I look at the Kerberos documentation for the library call to make a secure context, [`krb5_init_secure_context()`](https://web.mit.edu/tsitkova/www/build/krb_appldev/refs/api/krb5_init_secure_context.html#krb5_init_secure_context), I see this statement:

> Create a context structure, using only system configuration files. All information passed through the environment variables is ignored.

It sounds like `gssapi` may be somehow making a call to `krb5_init_secure_context()` and hence the trace logging configuration is being ignored.

Is there a way of turning on debug logging using `gssapi`? If `gssapi` is indeed creating a secure context, is there any way of turning on logging inside that context?

Comment: Are you perhaps running your flask server through 'sudo'? (If you are, /dev/stdxx won't work.)